# New Parse forces "optional", how to query a PFUser?

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfuser

I have this code that due to the x-code changes is no longer working.

```
    var query = PFUser.query()
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
    query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: "\(user)")
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
```

The problem is that the PFUser.currentUser()!.username  aka, the "user" variable now prints out the following : Optional("username")

Therefore, it searches for a username with the text: Optional("") and a username between the quotes.
So it doesn't find a username.

Ever since the last x-code update, the query is requiring this optional crap.

Comment: `query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: user)`? Why are you making a string with the _description_ of user in it?

Comment: i'm trying to pass in the username field.  Any way I do it, i get the extra Optional("") crap

Answer (score 1):

got it to work.

```
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query!.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
```

added a ! after username in PFUser.currentUser()!.username!

Comment: I just played with the println(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!) prints just the username, while PFUser.currentUser()!.username prints Optional"username"  No idea why.  If anyone understands the concept I'd appreciate an explanation.  I'm always trying to learn :)